# Define constants in mingw-gcc

Tags: gcc, g++, mingw

I am using mingw-gcc as my compiler in windows. I need to define constants in the environmental setting so when I am compiling a package the constant is automatically defined.

in Linux I usually do:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API ...
...
```

but in windows I have no idea how this can be done. Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Are you asking how to set environment variables in windows? If so, just replace `export` with `set`.

Comment: Hi Markku, I tried to use set CPPFLAGS=xxx but it doesn't work, not sure why. I will continue to investigate.